# Ensure npm install -g does not need sudo?

Tags: macos, npm, sudo

On MacOS X an `npm install -g` requires a user to sudo, though we would like to have it so the 'global' mode is per user, rather than system wide. Does anyone know if this is possible? We would like to avoid exposing sudo to non-admin users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3139) on this (currently marked closed at this time), on the NPM GitHub project. One person in the comment thread suggests:

> I personally `npm config set prefix ~/npm` and have `~/npm/bin` in my `PATH`